# ¿Cómo accedo al elemento en Selenium con Python?

Tags: python, selenium

Estoy empezando con Selenium y Python. Tengo problema de acceso a campo.

Código de acceso:

```
s=Service('C:\Drivers\chromedriver.exe')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
url='https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
browser.get(url)
browser.maximize_window()
#browser.find_element(By.ID, "//input[contains(@id,'mat-input-0')]")
#browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "//input[contains(@id,'mat-input-0')]")
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@id,'mat-input-0')]")
```

No se donde estoy fallando. ¿Es que el XPATH: "//input[contains(@id,'mat-input-0')]" no es correcto?

Este es el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como obtengo el Xpath:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba a no usar el XPath relativo, intenta usar el absoluto

Comment: Nada, me sigue saltando el error: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html[1]/body[1]/gc-root[1]/gc-plain-layout[1]/gc-login[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/mat-card[1]/div[1]/div[2]/gc-login-form[1]/div[1]/mat-card[1]/form[1]/mat-card-content[1]/gc-input[1]/mat-form-field[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/input[1]"}

Comment: El acceso al elemento lo haria asi: browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/gc-root[1]/gc-plain-layout[1]/gc-login[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/mat-card[1]/div[1]/div[2]/gc-login-form[1]/div[1]/mat-card[1]/form[1]/mat-card-content[1]/gc-input[1]/mat-form-field[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/input[1]")

Comment: Puede ser que como estás buscando por XPath relativo y en el método llamas por XPath a secas puede que te esté lastrando

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que Selenium se ejecute antes que la pagina cargue.

Agrega un `time.sleep(1)` antes de llamar al XPATH para que espere un segundo.